# use GitPython on remote machine

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, remote-access, gitpython

Using GitPython locally is peace of cake, I need clone, pull, commit git repository on remote machine.

I know I can wrap bash/git commands with paramiko, but I need find out if there is any way to do it with GitPython objects, maybe with help another python2.7 library.

Comment: Why not upload your script onto the remote machine via SSH?

Comment: Yes, I can. I just wonder how to operate on python objects and not scripts.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. But how about cloning repo to local machine, changing  branch locally, and pushing it back to remote server? BTW, you even don't need a running git server on remote machine, just  specify ssh://{user}@{host}/{path} instead of http/git repo address